# How to call external java functions from javascript code?

Tags: javascript, java

I have two separate java and javascript file. I want to call a method which is in my java class from my javascript function. Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: So you would ned to make a call to the server.

Comment: I think more context is needed.  Is this a Java function in an Applet?  Are you talking about a GWT problem?

Comment: Like @epascarello implied an ajax call to a servlet would normally work.

Comment: A few thoughts... You could use ajax to call what I assume could be a jsp page. Another option, use React JS or Angular JS to connect server-side.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the structure of your code looks like but you cannot call a java method directly from javascript. You would need to use something that can map your URL to the method you are calling. You would need to make a `servlet` or `JSP` and use an ajax call to communicate to the server and call your desired method.

The following tutorial should help you get started writing something like this:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/ajax-quickstart.html